# foreach loop for multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array with key value. I want to loop the data in that array but I don't know how.

This is my array:

```
{
  "success": "1",
  "order_details": [
    {
      "item_order": 5,
      "address": "155, Mani Nagar Society, Nana Varachha, Surat, Gujarat 395006, India",
      "contact": "95303709",
      "total_price": "3330.0",
      "order_place": "18-05-25 06-07-20",
      "preparing_date_time": "",
      "preparing_status": "Deactivate",
      "dispatched_date_time": "",
      "dispatched_status": "Deactivate",
      "delivered_date_time": "",
      "delivered_status": "Deactivate",
      "menu": [
        {
          "menu_name": "demo item",
          "item_amt": "200",
          "Ingredients": [
            {
              "ingredients_name": "burger",
              "ingredients_price": "200"
            },
            {
              "ingredients_name": "pizza1",
              "ingredients_price": "800"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I loop / foreach that array?

I guess there is a foreach inside a foreach, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: post your expected out put please

Comment: @RahulShrivastava Posted array is my expected output..

Comment: yeah i want to know which field you are trying to get

Comment: So you just want to print these key-values?

Answer (score 1):

In the manual of array_walk_recursive there is an example that might suit you.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true); //$str is your json string

array_walk_recursive($arr, 'test_print');

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "[$key]: $item\n";
}
```

https://3v4l.org/dVUMS

If you only want to output some elements of the array you can create an array with the items you want to output and pass it on the function.
Then use in_array to see if it's a output or not.

https://3v4l.org/8ZvUS

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
    <?php

$jsonData = '{
  "success": "1",
  "order_details": [
    {
      "item_order": 5,
      "address": "155, Mani Nagar Society, Nana Varachha, Surat, Gujarat 395006, India",
      "contact": "95303709",
      "total_price": "3330.0",
      "order_place": "18-05-25 06-07-20",
      "preparing_date_time": "",
      "preparing_status": "Deactivate",
      "dispatched_date_time": "",
      "dispatched_status": "Deactivate",
      "delivered_date_time": "",
      "delivered_status": "Deactivate",
      "menu": [
        {
          "menu_name": "demo item",
          "item_amt": "200",
          "Ingredients": [
            {
              "ingredients_name": "burger",
              "ingredients_price": "200"
            },
            {
              "ingredients_name": "pizza1",
              "ingredients_price": "800"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}';

$jsonDecode = json_decode($jsonData);



foreach ($jsonDecode->order_details as $orderDetail) {

    echo "Item order: " . $orderDetail->item_order;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Address: " . $orderDetail->address;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Contact: " . $orderDetail->contact;
    echo "<br>";

    foreach ($orderDetail->menu as $menuItem) {

        echo "Menu Name: " . $menuItem->menu_name;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Item amt: " . $menuItem->item_amt;
        echo "<br>";

        foreach ($menuItem->Ingredients as $ingredientsItem) {

            echo "Ingredients name: " . $ingredientsItem->ingredients_name;
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Ingredients price: " . $ingredientsItem->ingredients_price;
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Item order: 5
Address: 155, Mani Nagar Society, Nana Varachha, Surat, Gujarat 395006, India
Contact: 95303709
Menu Name: demo item
Item amt: 200
Ingredient name: burger
Ingredient price: 200
Ingredient name: pizza1
Ingredient price: 800
```